# Kubuntu 19.10 Not shutting down properly

Tags: boot, kubuntu, shutdown

I'm new here so let me know if I'm not following the posting rules properly.

I recently installed Kubuntu 19.10 on my new Asus Zenbook 15 (UX533), and I fixed nearly all of the boot issues that I was having (wouldn't launch without the boot disk, had to install the necessary NVIDIA drivers), but now it seems that my machine isn't properly shutting down. When I shutdown via any means (e.g. terminal, the desktop interface, or by pressing the power button) the input devices will cease to work and the screen will turn black as one would expect, but when I boot it up sometime later I find that my battery is completely drained, so I assume there must be some process still running in the background.

My system specs are as follows:

```
Intel i7-8565U
16 GB of RAM
1TB SSD
NVIDIA GTX 1050
```

I hope this is enough info to help diagnose the problem. I'll edit if there's anything else necessary!

Edit 12/16/19:
I am currently able to restart without any issue if I do not close the laptop lid, but my machine will sill only show a black screen with a single white underscore whenever I close the lid and reopen it. I updated my grub boot file as @DrNo suggested, but that did not solve this particular issue. I have double checked that my nVidia driver is functioning properly, so I am currently without direction.

Below is my /etc/default/grub file in case there's something I've missed.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash apci=off"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"


# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, you can install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. 19.10 is experimental compare to the LTS version, a new hardware is not tested yet, if you want to find what is wrong with these combination, that's welcome to the Ubuntu team. Then you should provide the syslog.

Answer (score 0):

if not already done, try adding the option: nouveau.modeset=0
in the GRUB command line (don't forget to update grub).
This solved the same issue for my kubuntu 19.10 fresh install.